# Configuring Third-Part Xbox 360 controller with Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: input-devices

I'm trying to set up a third party xbox 360 controller I got off of amazon but I'm not having any luck with it.  It reports to the OS as an official 360 controller, but neither `xpad` or `xboxdrv` seem to be working with it.  When it's connected to the computer, the green LEDs blink forever.

I get the following in dmesg when connecting the device:

```
[84734.680617] usb 1-3: new full-speed USB device number 12 using xhci_hcd
[84735.042706] usb 1-3: New USB device found, idVendor=045e, idProduct=028e, bcdDevice= 1.10
[84735.042708] usb 1-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[84735.042710] usb 1-3: Product: Controller
[84735.042711] usb 1-3: Manufacturer: ©Microsoft Corporation
[84735.042712] usb 1-3: SerialNumber: A0BD0B52
[84735.093762] usb 1-3: can't set config #1, error -71
```

Attempting to manually load `xpad` by running `sudo modprobe xpad` does nothing.  I'd heard that `xpad` can be a bit fickle, so I tried using the userspace `xboxdrv` program but that failed with the following when run as a standard user:

```
$ xboxdrv --quiet
-- [ ERROR ] ------------------------------------------------------
USBController::USBController(): libusb_open() failed: LIBUSB_ERROR_ACCESS
```

Running it as root gave the following message, even after `xpad` as confirmed removed from the kernel:

```
$ sudo xboxdrv --quiet
-- [ ERROR ] ------------------------------------------------------
 Error couldn't claim the USB interface: LIBUSB_ERROR_NOT_FOUND
Try to run 'rmmod xpad' and then xboxdrv again or start xboxdrv with the option --detach-kernel-driver.
```

While debugging I noticed a couple of strange errors in `usb-devices`.  I'm not entirely sure what to make of this. (Output is abridged)

```
$ usb-devices
T:  Bus=01 Lev=01 Prnt=01 Port=02 Cnt=01 Dev#= 12 Spd=12  MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=ff Prot=ff MxPS= 8 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=045e ProdID=028e Rev=01.10
S:  Manufacturer=©Microsoft Corporation
S:  Product=Controller
S:  SerialNumber=A0BD0B52
C:  #Ifs= 0 Cfg#= 0 Atr= MxPwr=
cat: '/sys/bus/usb/devices/usb1/1-3/1-*:?.*/bInterfaceNumber': No such file or directory
cat: '/sys/bus/usb/devices/usb1/1-3/1-*:?.*/bAlternateSetting': No such file or directory
cat: '/sys/bus/usb/devices/usb1/1-3/1-*:?.*/bNumEndpoints': No such file or directory
cat: '/sys/bus/usb/devices/usb1/1-3/1-*:?.*/bInterfaceClass': No such file or directory
cat: '/sys/bus/usb/devices/usb1/1-3/1-*:?.*/bInterfaceSubClass': No such file or directory
cat: '/sys/bus/usb/devices/usb1/1-3/1-*:?.*/bInterfaceProtocol': No such file or directory
/usr/bin/usb-devices: 76: printf: (none): expected numeric value
I:  If#=0x Alt= 0 #EPs= 0 Cls=() Sub= Prot= Driver=
```

One website I found while searching suggested adding `usbcore.autosuspend=-1` to the kernel command line via grub but that seems to have had no effect.  This is the second third-party xbox 360 controller I've bought that's displaying these kinds of issues, and I just want to figure out if it's because of some odd software configuration, or if I just got two bad devices.

As suggested in a similar poast, I plugged in the device while running `$ journalctl --follow` and got the following output which does not appear to contain any new useful information.

```
Oct 16 02:36:54 waffle kernel: usb 1-8.4: new full-speed USB device number 121 using xhci_hcd
Oct 16 02:36:55 waffle kernel: usb 1-8.4: New USB device found, idVendor=045e, idProduct=028e, bcdDevice= 1.10
Oct 16 02:36:55 waffle kernel: usb 1-8.4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
Oct 16 02:36:55 waffle kernel: usb 1-8.4: Product: Controller
Oct 16 02:36:55 waffle kernel: usb 1-8.4: Manufacturer: ©Microsoft Corporation
Oct 16 02:36:55 waffle kernel: usb 1-8.4: SerialNumber: A0BD0B52
Oct 16 02:36:55 waffle kernel: usb 1-8.4: can't set config #1, error -32
Oct 16 02:36:55 waffle mtp-probe[97045]: checking bus 1, device 121: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.3/0000:03:00.0/usb1/1-8/1-8.4"
Oct 16 02:36:55 waffle mtp-probe[97045]: bus: 1, device: 121 was not an MTP device
Oct 16 02:36:55 waffle mtp-probe[97048]: checking bus 1, device 121: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.3/0000:03:00.0/usb1/1-8/1-8.4"
Oct 16 02:36:55 waffle mtp-probe[97048]: bus: 1, device: 121 was not an MTP device
```